# Can anyone have a look at this code to solve the issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is a exercise from codecadamy, the following program is to find the total costing of a vacation which includes travel cost, plane cost as well as some spending money too. coming to the problem, in the last function i've entered 3 arguments days, city and spending money, but when i click the submission button it shows me to enter the argument in a correct manner.

[image][image]

Comment: You do have an indenting issue--your final `print` statement is currently *inside* the function `trip_cost`, *after* the `return` statement.

Comment: Also, I don't know that CodeAcademy means by "enter the argument in a correct manner," but you do have a logic issue--your hotel cost function logic refers to *nights*, but you've given it the number of *days*. In general, assuming you arrive and leave during the day, `nights = days - 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Newest issues**

- The `TypeError` complaining about adding `int` and `NoneType` is due to the issue pointed out by MarkG below: because you are not returning anything explicitly from `rental_car_cst`, you are implicitly returning `None` (note that this behavior is different from that of Perl or Ruby, both of which return the result of evaluating the last expression in the function). So you are adding an integer to `None`, which makes no sense.
- The `invalid syntax` error is due to the fact that Python does not allow assignment expressions to be used in `return` statements, so `return rental -= 50` is invalid (same for `-= 20` two lines later). Since `rental` is a local variable anyway, the assignment does nothing anyway, so you could just `return rental - 50`. Alternatively, you could take out the `else` and *unconditionally* `return rental`, and inside the `if` blocks just set `rental` correctly:

  ```
  if days >= 7:
      rental -= 50
  elif days >= 3 or days < 7:
      rental -= 20
  return rental
  ```

---

**First issue (old)**

I haven't used Code Academy, so I'm not familiar with what causes particular error messages, but the message you're seeing may be due to the fact that the Python interpreter *never sees* the call to the `trip_cost`, so of course you're not "entering the argument in a correct manner."

The reason for this, as mentioned in my comment, is that your `print trip_cost...` line is indented, so it's *inside* the `trip_cost` function. Thus the interpreter sees `import math` followed by four function definitions, and then the script ends...so none of the functions are *ever* actually called, and the interpreter exits without doing anything.

Comment: edited as per your request but resulted in something more awkward now :/

Comment: @chintusrikanth Would you mind deleting your original text block (since the code is no longer what you're using) and re-copying into a text block (since the picture makes it a little harder to see what's going on)?

Comment: I have some questions in my mind to put in front of you kyle strand.
1. How did the last return rental satisfied the whole functional block?
2. How exactly does it work and where it can be used?
3. Why does the print inside function didn't work out? if we mention a print inside the function how does it work?

sorry if my questions make you feel laugh, I'm a learner.

Comment: @chintusrikanth 1) I'm not sure why you'd expect it *not* to satisfy the whole block; many functions only have a single return statement. As soon as the interpreter encounters a `return` statement, control is `return`ed from the function, regardless of how it got there. Since you're setting the value of the `rental` variable inside the `if` block, then returning *that value*, the value that you've set is the value that gets `return`ed.

Comment: 2) This was mostly answered in (1). Note that the indentation is important; the `return` statement is *outside* the `if` block, so, because there's no `return` statement *inside* the `if` block, control will *always* get to the `return` statement (assuming no exceptions are thrown--i.e., that no drastic errors happen inside the `if` block).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71523/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-chintu-srikanth).

Answer (score 1):

Your function `rental_car_cost(days)` is not returning anything. You probably mean something like this:

```
def rental_car_cost(days):
    rental = 40*days
    if days >= 7:
        rental -= 50
    elif days >= 3 or days < 7:
        rental -= 20
    return rental
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment--it addresses one issue in the code, but it's probably not the issue causing the "enter the argument in a correct manner" message.

Comment: adding return statement in the rental function resulted in something mischevious, i've entered the screen shot. have a look onto it.

Comment: Please look at my answer again.